# Derivative of identity map and moving forms

Tags: differential-forms, exterior-derivative, cartan-geometry

So it's possible this question is simply "why is the derivative of the identity map on a manifold the identity on the tangent spaces?", but the context comes from reading Spivak's book about moving frames. I'll give enough here that you don't need that reference, I think.

So I understand we have a moving frame $(X_1(p),X_2(p),...,X_n(p))$ at a point $p$ on manifold $M_n$, and we can easily define "a" one-form,

$$\tilde{\omega}=\tilde{\theta}^iX_i$$

If $\tilde{\theta}^i$ are any particular one-forms on $M_n$ (or $T^*M_n$ I guess). And I also get that if we pick the dual one-forms such that $\theta^i(X_j)=\delta^i_j$, then that one form becomes an identity map, such that acting on a vector $V_p=V^jX_j(p)$

$$\omega(V_p)=\theta^i(V^jX_j)X_i(p)=V^j\delta^i_jX_i(p)=V_p.$$

(ok, I guess I'm slightly confused by this, since one-forms should act on vectors and produce scalars, but I think that's for a scalar-valued one-form...here we have a vector valued one-form $\omega$, so acting on a vector produces a vector...I think!)

The next thing is confusing to me. Apparently, if we take the identity map $P:M_n\to M_n$, we can actually identify $\omega$ with $dP$. This I don't understand - if I was going to take the exterior derivative of $P$, I would do something like

$$dP=\frac{\partial P}{\partial X_i}X_i+...$$

That's in the frame, not a coordinate system, so maybe I would do

$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial X_i}=\frac{\partial P}{\partial x^j}\frac{\partial x^j}{\partial X_i}$$

So even if I started thinking about Veilbien $x^i=e^{ij}X_j$ so that maybe $\frac{\partial x^j}{\partial X_i}=e^j_i$, so that $\theta^i=\frac{\partial P}{\partial x^j}e^{ij}$? But $\partial P / \partial x^j=1$ for each $j$....there's no index there and I'm just getting more confused.

Can anyone straighten this story out?

Answer (score 1):

This discussion is confused. Tildes appear and then disappear. A $1$-form is scalar-valued, unless you specifically speak of a vector-valued $1$-form or, more generally, a $1$-form with values in a vector bundle.

Remember that a linear map $T\colon V\to V$ can be viewed as a $(1,1)$-tensor, i.e., an element of $V^*\otimes V$. So, if $X_i$ is a basis for $V$ and $\theta^i$ is the dual basis for $V^*$, then the identity map is represented as the $(1,1)$-tensor $\sum \theta_i\otimes X_i$. That's all Spivak is doing with tensor fields (locally) on $M$. (If you consider the case that $M\subset\Bbb R^N$ for some $N$, then you can actually make sense of $\sum \theta^iX_i$ as an $\Bbb R^N$-valued $1$-form whose values happen to land in the tangent spaces of $M$.)

The discussion of Élie Cartan's $dP$ is meant to align with terminology from a century ago. But that's all that's going on. If you take the identity map $M\to M$, its derivative at a point is the identity map $T_pM\to T_pM$, and then you apply this discussion.

Comment: The disappearing tildes were deliberate - before they were the unique choice of dual one-forms, they could have been any generic one-form. And I think I explained my thoughts around where the 1-form took values. I would have appreciated confirmation or denial of that.

Although this answer is helpful, it is not complete. Perhaps you could provide an explicit form of P to demonstrate where $\theta^i \omega_i$ comes from?

Comment: Ah, I see now that the tildes were the general case. With regard to $P$, I did answer that. As you said, $P$ is the identity map. (But classically they thought of an "infinitesimal" change in the point, before differential forms became a rigorous thing.) Take $M_n =\Bbb R^n$ and literally take $P(x)=x$. Then $dP_x \colon T_x \Bbb R^n\to T_x\Bbb R^n$ is the identity map. Think of it as an element of $T_x^*\Bbb R^n\otimes T_x\Bbb R^n$. As I said earlier, if $M_n\subset \Bbb R^N$, think of the inclusion map $P\colon M\to\Bbb R^N$ and differentiate it as a vector-valued function, if you like.

Comment: I appreciate the effort here - but the inclusion is not illuminating to me. If we have coordinates on M (local $\mathbb{R}^n$), one could imagine the derivative of the identity in those coordinates just being the identity matrix. But, the moving frame approach is like an alternative to using a local $\mathbb{R}^n$ (right?), so I'd like to be able to take the differential of that directly, just referencing the moving frame. I was supposing this would happen if I went from the coordinates and back, using Veilbien, but I got confused. Maybe I'm just asking too much from the frame?

Comment: The frame will come from the mapping, typically. Take a look at pp. 101-105 (in particular, example 2) of my differential geometry text [just a brief section on moving frames], linked in my profile. You might also want to look at J. Clelland's lovely book *From Frenet to Cartan: The Method of Moving Frames* — lots of explicit computations and exercises.